# Forward downloads to a seperate physical connection

Tags: vpn, port, forwarding

So, mothers internet connection is incredibly slow, and she lives in a very rural area and cannot have anyway of acquiring a faster connection. I on the other hand have a very fast connection, would it be possible to have her connect to a VPN on my end and forward all of the download requests from her end to mine?

Comment: And how do you envisage the VPN-encapsulated downloads will get from you to her?

Comment: She'd be connected to your VPN via her slow connection, you know...

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was a way to have her connect to my modem and just use her connection as a bridge. I admittedly overlooked the fact that her connection would still be required and still be slow. Apologies, I'm new here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can use a VPN, but you should expect that to slow connectivity down even further.

Tunneling a slow site through a connection to a faster site is only going to give you any benefit, if you apply traffic shaping to the packets entering the tunnel from each end. And even then, it will only help if the slowness is due to other users transferring lots of data on the same link.

And if you do this just to apply traffic shaping, you still get an increased roundtrip time.